# Failure to connect to VNC server after upgrade to Fedora-20

Tags: linux, fedora, vnc, vncserver, fedora-20

On one of my servers (Chameleon - host for a number of VMs running different OS versions) I have two VNC server instances (Tiger VNC) on the host system - one for a root desktop and one for a plain user desktop. This was running well, until I upgraded from F19 to F20. Now I can't get into either VNC server from my desktop.

1) I can connect fine to a BASH root shell using SSH from my desktop, so it is not a general network connectivity problem.

2) I can also connect to the VNC server from the local desktop using VNC viewer to localhost:1. So the server instance is running and ready to receive connections.

3) I have verified using tcpdump that I get the packets on TCP port 5901.

4) I have turned all IPTABLES filtering off

5) I turned SELINUX off and rebooted. I also turned SELINUX on in permissive mode. I don't think it is a security labeling issue.

Any ideas for what to try next?

Comment: What happens when You run vncwiever from command line? May be some errors?

Comment: Connections attempts from my windows desktops just time out.

Comment: Connections attempts from the local command line (connecting to localhost:1) go through without a problem.

Comment: Check VNC listen on 5901 by `netstat -tlpn`

Comment: Hypothesis: vnc liston on 127.0.0.1, but not on 0.0.0.0

Comment: Xvnc is listening on 0.0.0.0:5901 as confirmed by "netstat -an" and also by "lsof | grep 5901"

Comment: Hard case, but I think solution is very simple. Try reproduce it with other TCP server, netcat for example, where connections logged.